# Selenim 4.7.2 + ChromeDriver 108 for Java fail with timeout during switching to iframe

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver, selenium-grid

**Prerequisites:**

There is an iframe on page with input fields which I need to get.
Before interacting with fields I must switch to iframe.

**Versions**

- Selenium has version 4.7.2 (I mean artifact with id = selenium-devtools-v108)
- standalone-chrome:108.0.5359.124
- chromedriver-108.0.5359.71

I faced issue related to switching to iframe. ChromeDriver cannot do this operation and fails with error:

> org.openqa.selenium.WebDriverException: org.openqa.selenium.TimeoutException: timeout: Timed out receiving message from renderer: 60.000

**Code which doesn't work:**

```
wait.until(ExpectedConditions.frameToBeAvailableAndSwitchToIt(
    By.cssSelector("#loginFrame")
));
```

**ChromeOptions**

```
            options.setExperimentalOption("excludeSwitches", List.of("--enable-automation"));
            options.setExperimentalOption("useAutomationExtension", false);
            options.addArguments("--disable-extensions");
            options.addArguments("--disable-gpu");
            options.addArguments("--disable-dev-shm-usage");

            options.addArguments("--no-sandbox");
```

I've already tried to downgrade ChromeDriver, Chrome, Selenium - nothing changed.

The most interesting is that tests are retried after fail 3 times and it doesn't work at first time, but it works as expected at second and third time at the same page.

Preventing questions like "Is there iframe?", I may say "Yes, there is". I checked it by separating waiting for element and switching to it: element has been found, but switching couldn't be executed.

And this code works fine on older version of page and *sometimes* - on current version. But the only difference between versions is changed styles of elements as I see in DOM (source code is external).

And so I have no idea what it is.

Answer (score 1):

It was happening because of frozen request which was in infinite loading and blocked Chrome. Blocking that request has solved my issue.